# Redactor plugin Code Mirror read only

Tags: redactor

I have redactor with plugin code mirror installed
however i want to put code mirror read only.

How can i do that the read only?
Thanks in advance.
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution

```
$('.CodeMirror > div > textarea').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

in init{} redactor calback